# identifying Button selection of each row in Tableview?

Tags: iphone

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ```
  UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  btn.frame = CGRectMake(230.0f, 4.0f, 60.0f, 36.0f);
  [btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickRename:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell addSubview:btn];

  return cell;
  ```

  }

but if the user selects the button on particular row, i can change that image through onClickRename...but can i get inwhich row's image has been touched  through

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath  ?

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like

```
[btn setTag:[indexPath] row]
```

in your cell setup, and then

```
- (void) onClickRename:(id)sender {
    int row = sender.tag;
}
```

you'd know which table row was hit.

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses the following technique in their [Accessory](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code:

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        // do what you want with the item at indexPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can set a tag for each button

Also, set each index value as its tag, we get to know which button is clicked at which row.

to set tag, in cellForAtIndexPath

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row


in button Action

@IBAction func anAction(_sender : AnyObject){

 let tappedButton = sender.tag // gives the row and button

}
```